Why different behaviour on two PCs, connected to the same Wi-Fi?
On my personal PC, I'm connected to the internet with my Wi-Fi router.
On my work PC, when being connected to the same Wi-Fi router, I see "No internet, secured".
How can I have different behaviour on the same Wi-Fi connection on two computers?

No internet, secured means that the connection can't contact the DNS server. Either the settings are different, or there's another problem on that pc preventing access to the DNS server.

Is the work PC actually not able to connect to your required work resources, or is the only symptom this message? The internet check on Windows computers requires access to a specific domain Microsoft controls. It does not actually mean your internet is not working, though for home users, it is a good basic check. Work network settings may not allow access to that check site. Please provide more details regarding other symptoms, but also not that this problem happening on your work computer means you should be asking your employer's designated support staff first.

There are a number of reasons why this can be, making this an extremely broad question!  Off the top of my head, some potential answers may include:

Static IPs - One machine may have a static IP address assigned which doesn't fit with the range of the router, making it impossible for the machine to get out to the internet.

Antivirus/Firewall/Security Software - Different security tooling may be slowing/stopping one machine from getting out to the internet.  Consistency between these should be checked to look for potential differences.  This also extends to patching and definition versions within this software

Drivers - Although quite unlikely, issues with drivers could be stopping full connectivity to your wireless network

Network Type - One device could be configured to view your network as a "public" network, while the other is configured to view it as "private"

Resolution - One device could have a proxy, different DNS Servers, WINS Entries, DNS cache, HOSTS file etc which is changing the behaviour of the resolution of addresses (and therefore stopping external connectivity)

3rd Party Applications - VPNs, proxy and tunneling services can make different devices behave differently

Frequency Selection - While extremely unlikely, I have previously seen it (once, a long time ago) where a 2.4GHz and 5GHz WiFi network with matching names has failed when one device connected to 5GHz and the 2.4GHz network was actually experiencing issues.

Windows Firewall - I have previously seen it enabled on one machine and disabled on another - inconsistency can produce inconsistent results.

Operating System - One Windows 8 and one windows 10/11 machine could exhibit different behaviours - although the external connectivity mechanisms should be the same between these if I remember correctly.


It could be any of these, or a combination, or none of the above - but without a lot more information, we're shooting in the dark a bit.

Your work computer is using a VPN. Your WIFI only provides access to the VPN and windows can't check if there is any internet access beyond that. Instead the internet access is provided through the work VPN.
